# Flutter - Not being able to change tab using a FAB instead of TabBar Icons

Tags: dart, flutter

I am trying to make a small notes app and I had the idea that instead of using a different page for the creation section of the app to use a different tab that is only accessible by an "add" fab in the main screen. Also I want it such that after you press the button it turns it into a "back" button which takes you back to the original page with the notes list.

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);
  static final _myTabbedPageKey = new GlobalKey<HomePageState>();
  @override
  HomePageState createState() => HomePageState();
}

class HomePageState extends State<HomePage> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  TabController tController;
  @override
  void initState(){
    super.initState();
    tController = new TabController(vsync: this, length: 2,);
  }

  @override
  void dispose(){
    tController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("NoteMe"),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: TabBarView(
          physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          controller: tController,
          children: <Widget>[
            new ListPage(),
            new CreationPage(),
          ],
        )
      ),
      floatingActionButton: actionButton(tController),
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.endDocked,
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
        shape: CircularNotchedRectangle(),
        child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            new Container(
                child: IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.search),
              onPressed: () {},
            )),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


//Implementing the ADD/RETURN Button as func
FloatingActionButton actionButton(TabController tC){
  bool isListPage = true;
  goToCreation(){
    if(isListPage == true){
      tC.animateTo(tC.index+1);
      isListPage = false;
    }
    else{
      tC.animateTo(tC.index - 1);
      isListPage = true;
    }
  }
  FloatingActionButton theButton = FloatingActionButton(
        backgroundColor: kColorPink,
        elevation: 2.0,
        child: isListPage == true ? Icon(Icons.add) : Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
        onPressed: goToCreation(),
  );
  return theButton;
}
```

As you can see the fab that is displayed is returned by the function above that also takes the tabcontroller as a parameter. I get no error message while running this. It simply does not work. I have tried not passing the tabController but instead accessing it through something like
    HomePage._myTabbedPageKey.tController.animateTo(...)

that I have found in another post but that's when I get an error message stating something like calling tController on null.
Sorry if I didn't format this well enough. This is my first post here

Answer (score 0):

It may be that the reference to **tc** or event  **goToCreation** is null.

Can you put a breakpoint in the method and check if the method is called and if the **tc** object is not null.